# Certain parts of rig not getting attached after parenting

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I'm trying to rig this model that I ripped from a game with the rigify metarig. After parenting the armature, the body doesn't want to be attached. The head gets attached but the hair doesn't want to move with it. The face's vertexes also move weirdly when moving the face bones, but I'm guessing that's because I haven't applied weight painting yet.

[image]

Comment: yes, use Weight Painting and also use the Assign button in the Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups

Comment: It shows the bones as assigned though, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Ah I get it now, still really confused about blender ui sometimes but it's working, thanks.

Comment: yes rigging is a big part, maybe follow some tutorials  ;)